# Custom TableViewCells are flickering while reloading tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

downloaded sample chat demo app from net. I have to change the layout direction of two custom cells (incoming messages left side, outgoing messages right side). Both incoming and outgoing cells layout direction are left as of now. So, I changed outgoing cells direction as right with **`UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft`**.

It is working fine with incoming messages left side, outgoing messages right side. But custom `tableview` cells are flickering while reloading tableview.

Please help me with this without changing the design of outgoing message cells.

Comment: Please share some sort of your code here to better understand your question.

Comment: Outgoing cells : dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.contentView.semanticContentAttribute  = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
        });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MovieCell";
    MoviesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
        // Even rows
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.contentView.semanticContentAttribute  = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
        });
    }
  
    return cell;
}

Comment: @HardikS Did you catch my point?

Comment: Add your additional code inside your question. Do you think it is easy to follow your code inside the comments here?
Also, I would suggest you create a custom tableView cell, where you would handle easily right/left alignment, otherwise, your layout looks very weird. On some cells the year of the movie is under the title, some other cells have it nearly in the middle. That's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `dispatch_async` stuff from `cellForrowAtIndexPath`.

That function is already running in the UI thread, so there is no need to dispatch anything into the main queue.

Also, since cells are being reused, you should also set the `semanticContentAttribute` to *left-to-right* when `indexPath.row%2 != 0`, because otherwise you'll end up in only right-to-left cells after scrolling a while:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MovieCell";
    MoviesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
        cell.contentView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
    } else {
        cell.contentView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight;
    }

    return cell; 
}
```

Comment: I want to show even rows are RTL and odd rows are LTR direction. that's my requirement without changing the design.

Comment: Yes, but you only set the RTL property. If a "even" RTL-cell is being reused on an odd row, it will keep it's RTL-property and will not be displayed as LTR, because in _your_ code UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight is never assigned.

Comment: I added timer     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(reloadTableView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  I noticed flickering here.   RTL and LTR behaviour is working on dispatch_async only.

Comment: Why would you reload the tableView every 5 seconds? That is not very performance-wise. Can you explain your requirements more clearly, and post your entire viewController inside your original question.

Comment: I want to reload tableview when I get new message. I added timer for testing purpose